# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str, when there is no float anywhere

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, types, typeerror

I have tried to do some JSON, then this error shows up -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Pycharm Projects/gloscrape/whole.py", line 61, in <module>
    data2 = '{"Percent":"' + \
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

I cant understand how float is related or why this isn't working...
I think the problem is with my JSON skills, I think i wrote it wrong somehow...
anyways if anyone can help me I'll be very happy!

bit more code if needed -

```
for x in range(len(nums)):
    file = open("updates" + str(x) + ".txt", "a")
    data2 = '{"Percent":"' + \
            element[x] + '", "diff":"' + diff + '"}'
    text = json.dump(data2 + '\n', file)
```

(element and diff defined earlier in the code)

Comment: Please add the content of `element` to the question and make sure that we can see the data types (e.g. by using `repr(element)` or the `pprint` module).

Comment: The error message pretty much tells you that `element[x]` is a float, so maybe `element[x]` is, in fact, a float? Hard to say since you don't provide the definition of `element`. Also hard to see why you're getting `x` out of `nums` but accessing something which looks unrelated.

Comment: why are you manually building  JSON string, then dumping it as JSON???

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are tying to do, but you are dump a string. Let `json`module serialize the data:

```
import json
nums = element = diff = ['foo', 1, 1.123]  # different types

for x in range(len(nums)):
    file = open("/tmp/updates" + str(x) + ".txt", "a")
    print(file)
    data2 = {"Percent": element[x], "diff": diff}
    text = json.dump(data2, file)
```

Data in updates2.txt:

```
{"diff": ["foo", 1, 1.123], "Percent": 1.123}
```